# How to add non unique value into a unique list while still allowing value to be updatable

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a simple database schema with User records

```
User
id - uuid pk
email - not null

List
id - uuid pk

List Entry
id - uuid pk
userId - uuid references User (id)
listId - uuid references ListEntry (id)
```

The trick is the system needs to guarantee uniqueness of User emails within a list while still allowing for the email of the User record to be updatable.

An obvious solution is the add email to the List Entry table with a unique index, but, this runs into issues with the requirement that the email is updatable.  Especially because the application treats a User as its own standalone entity that can be modified in a place that does not know about Lists and ListEntries.

I do control the code executing updates and I have considered attempting a solution using serializable transactions to prevent duplicates, but, that seems worse than trying to keep the two email fields in sync.

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? This seems like a job for triggers - and trigger code is highly vendor specific.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I am using Postgres. Its an interesting idea using triggers here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with this database, however I did add the relevant tag to your question, that should draw in the relevant people.

Comment: "*needs to guarantee uniqueness of User emails within a list*"  isn't that a simple unique constraint on `list_entry(list_id, user_id)`?  That would actually make `list_entry.id` redundant as a primary key.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Unfortunately, it is possible for multiple contacts to have the same email. This reflects the fact that contact info can come from multiple untrusted sources and cannot easily be merged automatically. As per the surrogate key, I have found in the past that it is much simpler if all tables contain a single column primary key. You are correct in that it is a bit redundant but the ease of use(Even if just in testing) is well justified.

Comment: For anyone who reads this post triggers in Postgres CANNOT be used to guarantee consistency across parallel transactions.